# Cannot login my koding vm via ssh by putty

Tags: authentication, ssh, putty, koding

I have followed all the instructions on the [page](http://learn.koding.com/ssh-into-your-koding-vm/) but still can not login. Nothing but just a blank black screen without any warnings.
I would be glad by any help.

Comment: Hi ,I have also tried on windows OS,I couldn't login using ssh. But than I tried using Ubuntu ,Now I can login using Ubuntu. :-) You also can use Virtual box and try to generate and login using ssh.

Answer (score 2):

this is how I did it with the help of this [guide](https://github.com/koding/kdlearn/blob/master/guides/connect-with-ssh-windows/index.md). You need **PuTTYgen** from [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

### Generating keys

Open PuTTYgen:

- Click on **Generate**
- Move mouse cursor until it's done
- Save public key (e.g. `public-key.txt`) and private key (e.g. `private-key.ppk`) using corresponding buttons.
- From the *Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file* box, copy its content.
- Close PuTTYgen

From the Koding VM:

- Create file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Open it, paste and save

Alternatively, you can go to your account settings -> SSH keys and past it here.

### Connecting with PuTTY

Get your *VM address* from your Koding workspace:

- On the top left, mouse over *koding-vm-0*, click on **...** that appeared, the VM address is right to **Assigned URL**, without "http://" (e.g. `unkk05c3f84e.joshmurray.koding.io`).

Open PuTTY:

- Set *Host name (or IP address)* as `username@VMaddress` (e.g. `joshmurray@unkk05c3f84e.joshmurray.koding.io`)
- Go to *Connection* -> *SSH* -> *Auth*
  Click on **Browse**, find your *.ppk* file (e.g. `private-key.ppk`)
- Go back to **Session**. Save your session (type a name under and click on Save)
- Click **Open** to connect

Hope it will help.